# Subtract two images to remove the background with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'am using OpenCV 2.4.5 to track a fish in real time. The fish is in a shuttle, also moving.
I get only frames from a gray-scale camera.

I try to get only the fish using those two images.
Before applying a threshold, I want to remove the background
I tried to subtract the two images, but it doesn't work with the parts outside the shuttle.

Here are the 2 frames, and my two results : https://app.box.com/s/3iug7wan8vz75j3usv7w

My code is as simple as that:

```
Mat fg = imread("fg.tif",1);
Mat bg = imread("bg.tif",1);

Mat result1 = abs(fg-bg);
imwrite("withoutMask.tif",result1);

Mat result2;
bitwise_and(fg, result1, result2);
imwrite("withMask.tif",result2);
```

It works when the fish stays in the shuttle, but not when he is out.
The problem is that the part of the tail outside the shuttle should have the same intensity as the part in.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use image ratio instead of subtraction. Ratio is better as it automatically scale out unnecessary objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But what do you mean by image ratio? I don't get it.
You know a function I could use?

Comment: You used A - B to detect the difference. I am suggesting A/B or B/A instead.

Comment: I tried to do something with ratio, but it wasn't successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a smooth pattern in every moves. The best way for video processing is to find moves and shifts in video.

Your problem is that the shuttle is moving and fish is swimming in it.

1) Calculate Motion Vector of small blocks of size 8 or 16 (or 4 if the image is low-resolution).

2) Using motion vectors of many small blocks and correlation between them you can identify the movements of few close blocks in a particular direction it is your object/fish (you will know approximate size and size variation of your fish :P)

3) The scene/background/shuttle is making rest of the large screen. Thus if you find lots of block with MV in same direction and magnitude then it is the background. You can suspect the shuttle with corners also.

Keep track of last position of fish to avoid huge processing by searching in the region close to last position rather than searching in whole image. (As I said movements are smooth and hence the next move will be very close the previous so no need to search whole image).

Answer (score 0):

there is a video module in opencv that provide some good background substraction algorithm, take a look at that: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractor

Moreover there is a useful discuss here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/7998/object-detection-using-background-subtraction/

Comment: Thank you for your reply Poko, but like I said the fish is in a shuttle moving too. My background is moving so I cannot use such algorithms.
I need to get the fish, only using those two frames.